# Combine 2 select queries into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I combine the below select queries into one?

```
select [Quantity] * UnitPrice as total 
from Store

SELECT dbo.Orderdetails.*, dbo.Store.* 
FROM dbo.Orderdetails 
INNER JOIN dbo.Store ON dbo.Orderdetails.Proid = dbo.Store.Pro_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sql you proide it would be as simple as the following.  Not sure if have actually provided the correct SQL however because I could imagine the unit price being in the store table, but quantity feels like it would come from OrderDetails, but I'm sure you can figure that bit out.

```
SELECT dbo.Orderdetails.*, dbo.Store.*, dbo.Store.[Quantity]*dbo.Store.UnitPrice as total
FROM dbo.Orderdetails 
INNER JOIN dbo.Store 
  ON dbo.Orderdetails.Proid = dbo.Store.Pro_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that that the unit price column is in the Store table and the quantity column in the OrderDetails table.
In that case you can include your expression in the second query like that :

```
SELECT dbo.Orderdetails.*, dbo.Store.* 
(dbo.OrderDetails.Quantity * dbo.Store.UnitPrice) as total
FROM dbo.Orderdetails 
INNER JOIN dbo.Store 
ON dbo.Orderdetails.Proid = dbo.Store.Pro_ID
```

Hope this will help